# ItextSharp add image on center of page with the text under it

Tags: c#, image, pdf, text, itext

I'm trying add picture on centre(middle) of page PDF file with text, but I can't do it right. I use for image `SetAbsolutePosition`, but text don't stand under picture.

I need in my Pdf file next format of page:
[image]

I use next code:

```
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);

                ITextEvents ev = new ITextEvents();
                writer.PageEvent = ev;
                doc.Open();

                var paragraph = new Paragraph();
                var paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
                var chunk = new Chunk("Text under picture", f14nb);
                var chunk1 = new Chunk("Code of picture", f14);

                img = ScaleImg(Image.GetInstance(imgNane_2));
                img.SetAbsolutePosition((PageSize.A4.Width - img.ScaledWidth) / 2,
                    ((PageSize.A4.Height - img.ScaledHeight) / 2));
                
                paragraph.Add(img);
                paragraph1.Add(chunk);
                paragraph1.Add(chunk1);
                doc.Add(paragraph);
                doc.Add(paragraph1);
                
                doc.Close();
```

---

```
private Image ScaleImg(Image img)
{
    if (img.Height > img.Width)
    {
        //Maximum height is 800 pixels.
        float percentage = 0.0f;
        percentage = 640 / img.Height;
        img.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
    }
    else
    {
        //Maximum width is 600 pixels.
        float percentage = 0.0f;
        percentage = 500 / img.Width;
        img.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
    }
    return img;
}
```

I think, that I should use another way for solve my problem, but I don't know which.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood how do it.

This is for image with text:

```
        public Image getWatermarkedImage(Document Doc, Image img, String watermarkText)
    {
        float width = img.ScaledWidth;
        float height = img.ScaledHeight;

        PdfTemplate template = cb.CreateTemplate(width, height);

        template.AddImage(img, width, 0, 0, height, 0, 0);
        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(template, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
            new Phrase(watermarkText, fontBold_14), width - 10, 10, 0);

        return Image.GetInstance(template);
    }
```

This is for adding text under image(main code):

```
                var codeOfPicture = "*Code of picture* - *Код картинки*";

                var chunk = new Chunk("Text under picture", font_14);

                img = ScaleImg(Image.GetInstance(imgNane_1));//imgNane_2));

                var tmpImg = getWatermarkedImage(doc, img, codeOfPicture);
                var textY = ((PageSize.A4.Height - img.ScaledHeight) / 2) - 15;
                var textX = PageSize.A4.Width / 2;

                tmpImg.SetAbsolutePosition((PageSize.A4.Width - img.ScaledWidth) / 2,
                    ((PageSize.A4.Height - img.ScaledHeight) / 2));

                doc.Add(tmpImg);

                ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(chunk), textX, textY, 0);
```